# Notifications dont work on real device but work on emulatok

Tags: android, notifications, sms, emulation

I am working on app that send encrypted SMS messages. I make it with receiver, so when encrypted SMS, public key or encrypted SMS key is received, notification is invoked. It works perfectly on emulator but on my phone, which has the same Android version, there are no notifications. Please do you have any idea where the problem may be? I add all my code that has something to do with notifications. Thanks for advices!

SMSReceiver.java :

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
    String sender="";
    String message="";
    SmsMessage[] msgs=null;
    if(bundle!=null){
        Object[] pdus=(Object []) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs=new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte [])pdus[i]);
            if(i==0){
                sender=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            }

            message=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        }
    }
    Intent i=new Intent();
    i.putExtra("type", message);
    i.putExtra("sender", sender);
    i.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
    context.sendBroadcast(i);


}

 }
```

MainActivity.java:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
PageIndicator mIndicator;
int Number = 0;


String phoneNumber;
String message;
IntentFilter intentFilter;
private static final int ID = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);


    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("sender");
        message = intent.getExtras().getString("type");
        getNotification();
    }
};

public void getNotification() {

    char key = message.charAt(0);
    String sentence = "";

    switch (key) {
    case '@':
        sentence = "Symmetric key received!";
        break;
    case '$':
        sentence = "Public key received!";
        break;
    case '£':
        sentence = "Encrypted SMS received!";
    default:
        sentence = "";
        break;
    }

    if (sentence.length() > 0) {
        final NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)     this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,     "Secure SMS notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new     Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Secure SMS notification!", sentence, i);
        mgr.notify(ID, note);
    }
}

 }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SMSListView"

        >
    </activity>
     <receiver 
        android:name=".SMSReceiver"      >

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @Mike M yes on emulator I get notification even when app isnt in the foreground and on the phone I dont get notification even if app is in foreground

Comment: @Mike M. I want to notify the user about received SMS and also when user click on notification, MainActivity will starts. Thi all works on emulator but dont on phone